# Action Script and MovieClip - how to unite several MovieClips?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I just started to read the book Learning ActionScript 3.0. So in the 3rd chapter the author covers EventLinsteners.

There's a sub-heading Event Propagation. From the beginning author creates to Folders on the Stage, with instance names Folder0 and Folder1 and explains Mouse_Over event. Than it says if you have 100 of such folders on your stage you'll have to write EventListener for every Folder instance. So they introduce some "strange for me" type of instance with name  folder_group, and it's like 1 MovieClip but with several MovieClips inside (I guess MovieClip is the correct reference).

So, shortly, in the next part of this chapter there's Frame Events sub-heading where Author has Unicycle. That unicycle is a single MovieClip too. It has to instances in it, when you double click it. The body instance and wheel instance.

So, how the hell should I do that. How to create such movieclip that has several different parts in it. When you double click it, you move from Scene1 -> "Some Name".

Please someone, explain how to do that... I tried to google it but to clue yet.

and one more thing. What's the difference between the separate ActionScript file and FLA-s ActionScript mode (I mean F9)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding event propagation you can look at [this link](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/eventbubbles-eventcancelable-and-eventcurrenttarget), the example swf shows bubbling/propagation and stoping propagation

by default, the click event will propagate, so as long as you attach the event to the top-level movieClip, you can set the action there.

you can try this simple test.  Create a MovieClip with a name "mc" and and put some other movie clips in there, using this code, any time you click on anything that is within that mc, an event will fire. if you name these movieClips, you'll see the names pop up, otherwise you should see names that are something like this "instance#"

```
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onHit);

function onHit(e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace(e.target.name);
}
```

having the code in an .as file makes it a lot easier to code. For example I do 99.7% of the coding in an external editor, and only use flash to create my graphic resources. 
You can use what's called a documentClass, which extends the default MovieClip that acts as the stage, most examples in adobe help are using these. For quick tests I just use the code panel(F9). The big difference really is that coding this way (using .as files) is a lot easier and faster, especially with an IDE like FlashDevelop, FlashBuilder, FDT etc.

---

for the fla you provided, you could use this for the doc class

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class FrameEvents extends MovieClip {

        public function FrameEvents() {
            cycle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onHit);
        }

        public function onHit(e:MouseEvent):void{
            trace(e.target.name);
        }
    }
}
```

you should see `body` traced when you click on the body, and `wheel` when you click on wheel

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for a fast reply. Thanks for explanations and definition of AS separate file. I thought so, just I was wondering if there's any other reason - so thanks for making it clear for me.

Comment: @Daniel 

I haven't tested the code you wrote here.. I think I'm not following you with the code. 
You wrote -- Create a MovieClip with a name "mc" and and put some other movie clips in there -- so you are using code. What I have in the exercise file is in Library I have 1 movie clip (maybe it's a symbol) that has two parts in it. I uploaded a file. Check it if you can. and see the unicycle example in FLA file with double click on it. That's what I want to create. See it, if it's the same what you wrote. here's the link, in the next comment.

Comment: updated the code, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what your goal is.

Comment: @Daniel  thanks Daniel... Actually I'm writing AS, but I ment, how to make in Flash a movie clip that has two or several movieClips inside. I don't mean the code, just visual part of Flash.

Comment: @Daniel

For example, I want to create a CAR, usual automobile. I have a door, wheels and the body of the car. I want the doors, wheels and body have different instance names so in the future I would call them smth like  car.door.rotation +=20; 

In the library I would like to have 1 Movie Clip CAR but actually CAR has several parts inside when I click on it on the stage in FLASH CS5, not using any AS. It's done the same way in the FLA file I atached previously.

Comment: @Daniel  I guess I made it... Insert -> New Symbol and there I put all the parts, Wheel and Body. So the result is that in the library I have 1 MovieClip (or maybe it's better to day symbol that is reusable) and by moving it to stage I have the whole Unicycle but the body and wheel have specific instance names.. so this is what I wanted to have. Can you tell me if this is write way to make it or there's a better practice?